# JBOSS 7.1.0 error - Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher

Tags: java, spring, resteasy, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate my spring MVC based REST application to Jboss 7.1.0. At startup, the Jboss initialisation shows that everything was started up correctly with all war files deployed successfully.

I had quite a few problems getting the integration between Spring MVN and Jboss's RestEasy service and im wondering if this is another conflict between jboss resteasy with Spring MVN.

When i make a request to the REST service i get the following error:

```
12:52:31,541 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-5) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3035 ms
12:52:31,845 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /MyRestService
12:52:31,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 53526ms - Started 390 of 468 services (72 services are passive or on-demand)
12:52:32,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "MyRestService.war"
12:54:10,117 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyRestService]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:35) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:121) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:107) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:84) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:225) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]

12:54:10,194 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyRestService].[javax.ws.rs.core.Application]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Allocate exception for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:35) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:121) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:107) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:84) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:225) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
```

The error does not make any sense and the only thing i recognise from it is the RESTEasy service servlet name. This is configured as follows - which works fine in Jboss 7.0.2

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Check this link https://community.jboss.org/message/718189?tstart=0&_sscc=t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm far from a REST expert, but [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) is not a servlet.

Comment: `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` ist the name of a Servlet which is internally defined and can be used in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 27):

I have also seen this exception when using RESTEasy on JBoss 7.1.1 (without Spring). It was wrapped like this:

```
Allocate exception for servlet [project class reference]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher
```

The solution was to exclude all RESTEasy jars from the war. In Maven, you can do this by ensuring any required RESTEasy dependencies are declared with Maven's 'provided' scope, as these are provided by JBoss, and excluding any transitive RESTEasy dependencies (see [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) for an example). You can check if you have any RESTEasy dependencies by changing to the directory containing your pom.xml and issuing a command such as:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep "resteasy"
```

If you are using your web.xml for JAX-RS activation, you may also need to switch to the class-based approach demonstrated [in the RESTEasy docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e127). These solutions to this issue are mentioned by a RESTEasy developer [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.resteasy.user/127) and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.resteasy.user/289).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the way RESTful service are declared, that way is quite standard for JAX-RS 1.1 (nothing to do with Servlet James !!), but it's a bug in JBoss, you need to specify the RESTful resources inside an Application subclass, otherwise it will try to mount AsyncDisp*** as a RESTful service.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problems by doing the following steps:

Step 1. Create your service registration class

```
public class RESTApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public RESTApplication () {
    singletons.add(new RestService());
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
```

}

Step 2: Edit your web.xml

```
<!-- Resteasy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>yourpackage.RESTApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*
    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```